# Calculate probability from 1 node to another in a adjacency matrix of probabilities

Tags: matrices

Given a adjacency matrix **A** like the following:

```
0.50  0.25 0.25   
0.25  0.50 0.25   
0.25  0.25 0.50
```

Where each line **i** and column **j** represents a Node and  **A(i,j)** represents the probability of get from Node **i** to Node **j**.

How to calculate the probability of exit from a given Node and get to another one in **k** transitions ?

Comment: That looks like a *Markov Chain*. As far as I can understand, you want to find the distribution after $k$ steps. Am I right?

Comment: Do you mean *in terms of $k$*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should calculate the matrix power $A^k$.  The $i,j$ entry of the result is the probability of going from node $i$ to note $j$ in exactly $k$ steps.